# Brother DCP-145C printer problem

Tags: printer, printing

I have a Brother DCP-145C printer installed and it does not print black ink. I tried running diagnostics and test pages, the driver is installed properly. It doesn't matter if I send the data from the pc, or use the scanning function. What could be the problem? Printer is brand new by the way, should i return it?

Comment: The black ink doesn't print if the heads need cleaning. Try running the cleaning function and see if it improves. You may have to run it multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

`Brother DCP-145C` printer doesn't print in black if the color cartridges are out-of-ink.

Check if:

1. **the color cartridges are installed properly**
2. you can print in color without problems

Answer (score 2):

If the printer stood in some storage facility for a long time the ink can dry and/or the heads can be clotted. Try using the cleaning function. If this doesn´t work you can also wet a paper tissue and put the ink cartridge on it to see if there is some ink coming out of it. But be sure that the tissue is just minimal wet and not dripping of water ;-)

When this doen´t bring up some color, it might be the head. I don´t know how the Brother DCP-145C is built so I can´t tell you if you can replace the head by yourself. So, you maybe should use the varanty. You also could try the e-mail function on the [support site](http://www.brother-usa.com/askus/default.aspx) of brother. They might give you the proper solution because they (like exwyz said) confirmed the problem. I already used this function to get support for some fax-devices. It worked fine an I got my problem solved with theyr help ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I have sent back to Brother Service Center twice already. Brother has confirmed that the print head is the problem. Met someone having same problem on DCP 165.

Comment: It took you nearly a year to post this as a reply and you also created a new account when doing so?